# Print a PCB layout several times in the same sheet at once in Proteus

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, proteus

How can I replicate my layout so I can print several of them in the same sheet without having to do it manually (printing one layout each time and setting its position relative to the previous printing)?

In this layout example, the sheet has room for nine of them.

PS: as the image shows, I'm using Proteus/Ares version 6.9.

[image: ares]

Comment: You could select the whole layout and copy&paste it 9 times on the same sheet..

Comment: According to one version of the manual I found online, "panelization" (probably the term you're looking for) is handled by the "Gerber Viewer" module, whatever that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Panelisation (which it what you're trying to do) isn't possible in the printer output. However, Ares does have a panelisation mode, and if you use that to create your multiple copies the printer mode will output them all just fine.

It is a bit of a roundabout way of doing things (intended for manufacture rather than printing, one presumes), but this it how you do it:

- Export the design as gerber output.

[image]

- Use the Gerber viewer mode to view the gerber output. Make sure you tick the panelization mode option.

[image]

- Use block copy to copy the layout how you want it, then...
- Output to the printer as you were doing before.

Answer (score 1):

When you done or have project backup, you can copy block, paste it everywhere as you want, then print it in usual way or export to PDF.
After you can decide if you'll save or not project with copied blocks.
[image]